# Copy-Paste Paragraph from PDF to LaTeX with accents

Tags: pdf, latex

I have a pdf file in Spanish with words like Hipergráficas or año. But when y tried to copy-paste (e.g. Word or Pages) those words looks like Hipergr'aficas and a~no.

I've tried to open with many text editor without any results.

Comment: Which engine do you use for compiling? pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex or something else? Which settings for the `fontenc` package do you use? Best thing would be to add a minimal working example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: pdflatex, using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: How do you open the pdf to copy the text? If I open `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
Hipergráficas or año.
\end{document}` with preview or adobe reader copy+paste works without decomposition of the glyphs.